# Change image src without refreshing from mysql database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, image, src

I am a bit of a pickle right now: I have an image displayed on my website, which has an src from a mysql server, it looks like this:

```
echo '<img src = "'.$sourceVariableFromDatabase.'" class = "profileImage" id = "profilePicture" />';
```

Also on my site, is a function that changes the database, and hence the value of `$sourceVariableFromDatabase`. However, the image won't update until the page is refreshed, but I would like it to display the new image src from the databse without refreshing.

I know this can be done through jQuery, but am unsure as to how to get the value from a database, as Javascript is not a server side, like javascript, and **as far as I know** cannot access databases in mysql.

How can I achieve this in Javascript/jquery.

Thanks, I have tried to be as clear as possible, and apologise for any waffle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery can be used to call a URL that returns data (e.g. HTML, JSON, text, etc). How that URL returns data can be however you want (PHP+MySQL, etc). Once JQuery receives the response, it can then update the `img` tag.

Here is a simple example:

Example HTML

```
<img id="profilePicture" src="(your source from db1)" />
```

Example JQuery on HTML page

```
function update_image(db)
{
  // get new image src
  $.get('some/url/to/get/new/src', {db: db}, function(response){
    // update the img src
    $('#profilePicture').attr('src', response);
  });
}
```

Example page (/some/url/to/get/new/src):

```
<?php

// get request data
$db = $_GET['db'];

// get img src
$src = some_function_to_get_src($db);

// output src
echo $src;
```

Comment: What is the new_src bit in the jquery, I don't understand, thanks.

Comment: That should've been `response` (fixed).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('/pathToCode', function(imagePath){
    $('#profilePicture').attr('src', imagePath);
});
```

The file at `/pathToCode` would need to query the database and echo the path to the image. Just add this code to the end of your function that changes the database.